# kogito-quarkus extension is missing in https://code.quarkus.io/

Tags: quarkus, kogito

I am trying to create a sample project in quarkus with kogito but I am not able to find the extension in code.quarkus.io. When trying to open the link to the extension, I get the follwing message `'org.kie.kogito:kogito-quarkus' is missing from the current stream '', it has been unselected.`

Is this extension disabled or not supported anymore?

[image]

Comment: Kogito is not supported yet on Quarkus 3.x. Accodring [this answer](https://groups.google.com/g/kogito-development/c/0JdV0q-EZlA) it's work in progress.

Comment: Okay, how about Spring? I couldn't find the kogito dependency there!

Comment: Spring3 is also out of the scope atm, we are working on upgrading to jakarta. As soon as we get there, we will update support for both frameworks.